# Detect closed non-blocking stdout/stderr pipes in python subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, posix

I am using Python to run a process interactively.

```
p = Popen ("/path/to/my-executable", stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=1)

for f in (p.stdout, p.stderr):
    flags = fcntil.fcntl (f, fcntl.F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK
    fcntl.ftcntl (f, flags)

for line in sys.stdin:
    p.stdin.write (line.encode ('utf-8'))
    ...
```

Suppose I read a command from stdin and forward it to `my-executable` via `p`, this process may or may not output anything to stdout/stderr, and it may or may not terminate.

I want to wait until `my-executable` "does something" before reading another command from stdin.

I tried this with `bash` as a subprocess and `"exit"` as the `line` written to its stdin, when I read from its stdout and sterr, stdout gave `None` and stderr gave `b''` but I don't expect this is a reliable indication that a process has finished running (i.e. I cannot reasonably `p.wait()` because there is nothing in that result which decisively tells me that the process will not give any more output).

How do I correctly make this Python script wait until

- something is written to stdout or stderr OR
- stdout or stderr is closed

?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`selectors`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/selectors.html) for that, like this:

```
# one-time setup
import selectors
sel = selectors.DefaultSelector()
sel.register(p.stdout, selectors.EVENT_READ)
sel.register(p.stderr, selectors.EVENT_READ)

# each time you want to wait
sel.select()
```

I'd recommend that you use unbuffered I/O, though, rather than line-buffered I/O. Also, you can do `os.set_blocking(f.fileno(), False)` to make your FD's non-blocking, rather than having to mess with `fcntl` yourself.